# Symfony how to add a user

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a user in the database from the PHP controller in Symfony.

I make the user entity with userInterface implementation, add up Security firewall with sha512 encode.

To insert the user I add new route:

```
user_create:
       pattern: /create_user/{email}/{password}
        defaults: { _controller: MyBundleBackendBundle:Security:create }
```

And add new method in Security controller:

```
public function createAction($email,$password) {

}
```

What code do I use inside the PHP controller action to create a user in the database with sha512 with a salt?

Comment: Are you seeing an error message, or are you looking for direction? Can you clarify what the actual question is here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How to add a user in symfony from code:

```
public function createUserAction($email,$password) {

    $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');

    $user = new User();

    $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
    $user->setSalt(md5(time()));
    $pass = $encoder->encodePassword($password, $user->getSalt());
    $user->setEmail($email);
    $user->setPassword($pass);
    $user->setActive(1); //enable or disable

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('Sucessful');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a read through [Security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) and [How to implement a simple Registration Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html)

If you are making a generic login/registration system [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) is a good option.

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbe but I no need a form, and this example is with plain text not with sha512 and salt field, how this tutorial help me ?

Comment: I don't you want do for me the code, I can save any thing inside a user entity, but how i save sha512 and salt fields? exists any predefined method o i wil make manually? In this manual i not see any solution. I try this with google and I'm lost

Comment: look at http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password